# Wicket Checkgroupselector not working

Tags: checkbox, wicket

my first question here. Hope I don't mess up too bad...

My problem is with the Wicket CheckGroupSelector. It doesn't work!

Here is the relevant code:

```
CheckGroup<AccountModel> groupMemberRecipients = new CheckGroup<AccountModel>("groupMemberRecipients", new ArrayList<AccountModel>());
groupMemberRecipients.add(new CheckGroupSelector("groupMemberSelector"));

ListView<AccountModel> memberRecipients = new ListView<AccountModel>("memberRecipients", groupParticipants) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<AccountModel> item) {
        item.add(new Check<AccountModel>("groupMember", item.getModel()));
        item.add(new Label("memberName", item.getModelObject().getFullName()));
    }
};

memberRecipients.setReuseItems(true);
groupMemberRecipients.add(memberRecipients);
```

And the relevant html code:

```
<span wicket:id="groupMemberRecipients">
    <input wicket:id="groupMemberSelector" type="checkbox"><b> Participants</b></input>
    <div wicket:id="memberRecipients">
        <input wicket:id="groupMember" type="checkbox"/><span wicket:id="memberName"></span>
    </div>
</span>
```

I basically followed the wicket example of a Checkgroup word for word. On the form submit, I can retrieve the selected options just fine. Only the select/deselect all checkbox at the top doesn't work. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Using wicket 6.9.1 btw

Comment: Looks good to me. Please check the console for any JavaScript errors and try with 6.11.0.